# How to restore old screen power-off effect on android 5

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

I upgraded to android 5 and the screen power off effect which was imitating power off of these old CRT monitors is lost. Is there any way for me to restore it?

Comment: You can try installing [Screen Dimmer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sebmorand.brightcom&hl=en) application available over the Google Play Store. One more thing I can't understand about what screen dim effect you are talking about ?? Are you talking about the screen dimming effect over the JellyBean environment or your are talking about something else.

Comment: Nexus 5 comes with KitKat (4.x android) and this was the default effect when you turned off the display using power button.

Comment: Pardon me I need to correct myself over the above post actually I was talking about the KitKat but I seemed to have typed Jellybean above ! anyway I would say that's something which we can't change I would say I have tried searching for an application which can do this but it seemed that there's nothing I can find anyway better to wait a bit more while to see if others members have something which can help you out !

Comment: I believe the only way to change it is to install a custom ROM that supports the effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have rooted your device then [Xposed Installer](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) can do this. 
[Xblast tools](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-xblasttools-quiethours-centerclock-t2294419) & [GravityBox](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-gravitybox-v3-1-4-tweak-box-android-t2316070) are xposed modules that have crt off and many other effects.

Answer (score 0):

The old way was to manipulate certain parts of the code in the framework-res.apk file and then update somethings in the build.prop of the device. Of course this was when I was running Gingerbread (2.3) on my Samsung device. As of now, you could look into the system packages of latest Cyanogenmod git branch/ or wait for CM12.